# CountZeroes in java

Tags: java

I don't know where am I going wrong. I want to count zeroes via recursion but I am not getting it:

```
public class countzeroes {

    public static int countZerosRec(int input){
      int count=0;
      return countZerosRec(input,count);
    }

  private static int countZerosRec(int input ,int count){
      if (input<0) {
          return -1;
      }
      if(input==0) {
          return 1; 
      }
    int m = input%10;
    input = input/10;
    if(m==0){
      count++;
    }
    countZerosRec(input,count);
    return count; 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(countZerosRec(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the correct result of a sample number? for example 120100. Is the correct answer 3?

Comment: You ignore the result of the recursive call `countZerosRec(input,count)`.

Comment: @hamidghasemi it should be 3 but its giving 0

Comment: @AndyTurner  how should i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method as below. Return `count` always

```
private static int countZerosRec(int input ,int count){
    if (input <= 0) { // check if input is negative or zero
        return count;
    }

    int m = input % 10;
    input = input / 10;

    if (m == 0) {
        count++; // increment if current digit is zero
    }

    return countZerosRec(input,count); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method would be:

```
public class countzeroes {

    private static int countZerosRec(int input){
        if (input<0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (input==0) {
            return 1;
        }

        if(input < 10) {
            return 0;
        }

        int m = (input%10 == 0)? 1: 0;

        input = input/10;

        return m + countZerosRec(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(countZerosRec(n));
    }

}
```

Let me explain 2 problems in your code:

1- First of all, your second `if` statement (`if(input == 0)`) ruin everything. Consider `1200100` as an example. In the 6th round of recursion the input would be 1, and if you divide it on 10 the result is 0 (which is the input of next recursion round) and therefore all the answers would be 1.

2- Secondly, it would be nice if you don't change the input parameter in your code. because it's completely error-prone (In complicated codes, you can not trace the changes happen on a parameter and it makes debugging hard). So, I just removed the `count` parameter from the input.

And finally, It is better to name your classes in CamelCase form. (`CountZeroes`)

Comment: This looks good, but `countZerosRec(0)` will return 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you're right. let me correct that.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I just added another `if` statement to check zero.

Answer (score 1):

Put `return count` in if(input == 0) statement and instead of
`countZerosRec(input, count); return count;` put `return countZerosRec(input, count);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int zeroCount(int num)
{
    if(num == 0)
       return 0;

    if(num %10 ==0)
        return 1 + zeroCount(num / 10);
    else
        return zeroCount(num/10); 
}
```

this would work

Answer (score 0):

Your count logic is excellent. 
in below line ... you are making logic mistake..     just fix it.

```
    private static int countZerosRec(int input, int count) {

        if (input < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (input == 0) {
         return count;

            //return 1; /// you need to change your code here, in last its getting zero as (num < 10 )/10 is 0
            // its entering here everytime, and returning one.
            // since its the base condition to exit the recursion.

// for special case of 0 (zero) count, handle your logic when it is //returned.
    //...... rest of your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams:

```
System.out.println("11020304".chars().filter(c -> c == '0').count());
```

Result: 3